# Can't link against `libPocoFoundation` Poco C++ Framework

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared-libraries, poco

After installing Poco on my Linux workstation (I tried both - latest version from source and older version from the `apt-get` package manager) I can't link against the `libPocoFoundation`.

When I try to compile any code with `g++`, having appended the `-lPocoFoundation` flag I get errors like:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -lPocoFoundation main.cpp -o main
    main.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `Poco::ThreadPool::joinAll()
    main.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `Poco::ThreadPool::available()
```

I explicitly checked for the existence of the `libPocoFoundation.so` in my `/usr/local/lib/` directory and it's ok.

Why can't the linker find the Poco shared library?

Below is an extract from the DUMP of `readelf -s`:

```
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 5732 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND waitpid@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
     2: 00000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZTIi@CXXABI_1.3 (3)
     3: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_mutex_destroy@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
     4: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSo3putEc@GLIBCXX_3.4 (4)
     5: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND chmod@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
     6: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getrusage@GLIBC_2.0 (5)
     7: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_getspecific@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
     8: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcS@GLIBCXX_3.4 (4)
     9: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Znwj@GLIBCXX_3.4 (4)
    10: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSt8__detail15_List_nod@GLIBCXX_3.4.15 (6)
   206: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_join@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
   211: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_rwlock_rdlock@GLIBC_2.1 (8)
   223: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_setschedparam@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
   224: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_cond_timedwait@GLIBC_2.3.2 (16)
   227: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_cond_wait@GLIBC_2.3.2 (16)
   246: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND pthread_self@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
```

`readelf -S`:

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1a1cdc:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            00000114 000114 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 2] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        00000138 000138 00a4d8 04   A  3   0  4
  [ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000a610 00a610 016640 10   A  4   1  4
  [ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB          00020c50 020c50 03677f 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 5] .gnu.version      VERSYM          000573d0 0573d0 002cc8 02   A  3   0  2
  [ 6] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0005a098 05a098 000220 00   A  4   7  4
  [ 7] .rel.dyn          REL             0005a2b8 05a2b8 008700 08   A  3   0  4
  [ 8] .rel.plt          REL             000629b8 0629b8 003598 08   A  3  10  4
  [ 9] .init             PROGBITS        00065f50 065f50 00002e 00  AX  0   0  4
  [10] .plt              PROGBITS        00065f80 065f80 006b40 04  AX  0   0 16
  [11] .text             PROGBITS        0006cac0 06cac0 0d89d8 00  AX  0   0 16
  [12] .fini             PROGBITS        00145498 145498 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
  [13] .rodata           PROGBITS        001454c0 1454c0 01c8e0 00   A  0   0 32
  [14] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        00161da0 161da0 00732c 00   A  0   0  4
  [15] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        001690cc 1690cc 024140 00   A  0   0  4
  [16] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        0018d20c 18d20c 00bc6c 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      001997e0 1997e0 000084 00  WA  0   0  4
  [18] .ctors            PROGBITS        00199864 199864 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .dtors            PROGBITS        0019986c 19986c 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        00199874 199874 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        00199880 199880 005d14 00  WA  0   0 32
  [22] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0019f594 19f594 000108 08  WA  4   0  4
  [23] .got              PROGBITS        0019f69c 19f69c 000950 04  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0019fff4 19fff4 001ad8 04  WA  0   0  4
  [25] .data             PROGBITS        001a1acc 1a1acc 0000e4 00  WA  0   0  4
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          001a1bc0 1a1bb0 0007a8 00  WA  0   0 32
  [27] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 1a1bb0 00002a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 1a1bda 000101 00      0   0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `nm --demangle /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so` and check if these symbols are defined there.

If the symbol has `U` in left column of `nm` output, it's undefined and you have to find it somewhere else.

Comment: It says "No symbols"!?!? How is it possible? What am I missing?

Comment: @ItayGrudev it may be compiled for another platform. Try `readelf -h` and check `Class:` and `Machine:` fields.

Comment: `Class: ELF32` and `Machine: Intel 80386`. It is correct, but still no symbols are found. I did even tried the newest version `1.5.2` and still have the same problem.

Comment: For starters, `readelf -s` indicates there are indeed no such symbols (you may need to look at demangled version to be sure, can use `nm --demangle`).

Comment: Ah, you posted extract from `readelf -s` output. What you have to do is use `nm --demangle` and look for symbols which are mentioned as undefined. You can determine this as I described in the answer.